# How to get a friends user wall from facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to read my friends posts (feeds?, all posts but for a specific user only) from his user wall.
I need all (posts, feeds, statuses) that i see when i look at his page directly from the website.

I use the android sdk and i tried the graph api and rest method.

My app is registered and i have logged in facebook to get the access token (permission: read_stream)
but i dont get that infos that want to.

Please help.
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

You need them to actually *use* your app and grant full permissions via the graph API. 
You cannot simply 'grab a friends wall'. You must do that via your app and it needs the permissions to do so from the user in question.

Comment: but what permissions i have to set?

Answer (score 0):

How about testing your Graph API call in the Graph API Explorer?
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

In my case, I could get my first 10 friends' feed (wall) with the url https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=friends.limit(10).fields(feed)

Note that I used field expansion of the Graph API.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/

Comment: i know the graph api explorer and i tested with it, but i dont understand how to read the friends wall posts entries, to see the same when i go to his wall in browser. i want to read only specific friends of me, not all.

Comment: do you have no other hint for me? maybe i could filter my home feed for a specific friend to get the infos i want to?