# Android: How to fetch posts from a Facebook friend wall using Graph APIs

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Working Environment:** Android Studio 1.0.2 + Facebook SDK 3.22.0 + Java

**My question consists of two parts:-**

**P1:** Is it really true that if I want to fetch one of my friends posts, s(he) must use my application first and grant it the required permissions? or this was an old technique: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209451/how-to-get-a-friends-user-wall-from-facebook)

**P2:** How can I fetch - Using code - posts from my friends walls?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the wall of friends. You can only get the wall posts of the authorized User. Friend permissions are gone completely, you are not supposed to read the wall of a friend for privacy reason.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Code about getting the wall posts can be found in the Facebook docs too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. By 'authorized User' you mean that in my application I can get wall posts of the user of my application, right?

what about getting the posts by other users of my application who are also friends of one of my application users?

Comment: I pressed enter mistakenly... So how can any developer create a Facebook application like the one provided by Facebook company? And what is the privacy problem of fetching public posts which can be accessed via PC browser?

Comment: Just because something is Public doesn't mean the user want any app to read it

Comment: @WizKid Thanks for your response, but it's not the "Any app" that want to read the public posts of the Facebook users, it's one of their friends how logged in using this application and granted permissions - if any - and want to use this application to write on their wall or read / like / comment on their posts. And again, so there is no other companies but Facebook allowed to create a mobile Facebook application?

Comment: Ok, just because my friend is using some random app doesn't mean I want that app to read my posts.

Yes read_stream will not be granted to apps on Android and iOS

Comment: Well, that's shocking news to me, but I'm sure FB team has reasons to apply such strict rule, still there could've been a better solution, say, not allowing 3rd party apps to access posts not public (as shared with friends only posts), but public posts are meant - by its owner - to be available for everyone. In all cases, thank you for your help :)

Comment: You are saying "Yes read_stream will not be granted to apps on Android and iOS", is that mean it's still active with an expiration / deprecation date? Or it already has been deactivated? P.S: I'm still new with FB SDK.

Comment: And to be fully aware of this privacy rule, let's say two of my customers using my application and granted it required permissions, still they can't access each other posts using my application?

Comment: you can only use read_stream with an app created before april 2014 and only until april 2015 - not worth it to create any app with that permission anymore, even if you got an old app.

Comment: if 2 friends both authorize your app, you can read the wall posts of each one of them with their own user token only. so if you want to read the wall of a friend (who is using your app too), you would have to store the user token of that friend and use it later. the question is: why would you even need the wall posts of the authorized user and why would you need access to the wall of the friends? what for?

Comment: BTW, why I can't find a documentation about filtering requested posts, in FB documentation I find it null, how can I filter my HttpMethod.GET request to fit a specific criteria (Type - Date - etc.)?

Comment: you can't filter, you would have to go through all posts an filter on your own.

Comment: That would be a resource consuming process on user's end ... In all cases, thank you for all the help, it's really appreciated :)

Comment: well, keep in mind that it would be a resource consuming process on the facebook servers if they would allow filtering. better put it to your own server or the client, to keep the API fast.